# What dose @Trivial mean in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

I have seen `@Trivial` in some Java code in couple of places like this:

```
@Trivial
public final class XYZ {...}
```

What does it mean?
What effect does it have?

Comment: `"I have seen @Trivial in Java in couple of places ..."` -- Where **excatly** have you seen this? I've not seen this, and I'll bet that it is a locally defined custom annotation. Some context please.

Comment: Annotations can be created custom, and this looks like a custom annotation for someone, and quick guess: this class doesn't need JavaDoc because its functionality is trivial.

Comment: @m0skit0 Good point!
I'll take that as an answer, if you would add it as one:)

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy I don't think a guess is a good answer. If you have no further context, we should probably just delete this question. This question is already the second hit on Google for `Java @trivial annotation` (i.e. no-one else is using this).

Comment: Maybe this one? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.spi.logging_1.0.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/ras/annotation/Trivial.html?lang=en

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, that's is all the context I can provide. However I'm satisfied with the answer I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations can be created custom, and this looks like a custom annotation by someone. Example (from my code):

```
/**
 * Because I never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down!
 * 
 * @author m0skit0
 * 
 */
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RickAstley {

}
```

Bonus quick guess about `@Trivial` meaning: this class doesn't need JavaDoc because its functionality is trivial.